# About python's return value

Tags: python

```
    def createMenu(self, menuData):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        for eachItem in menuData:
            if len(eachItem) == 2:
                label = eachItem[0]
                subMenu = self.createMenu(eachItem[1])
                menu.AppendMenu(wx.NewId(), label, subMenu)
            else:
                self.createMenuItem(menu, *eachItem)
        return menu
```

In this code,the return value is `menu`.it refers to the Object `wx.Menu()` . This Object is a local Variable. And it will be deleted when this function call goes over.But the next code in the book is
`menuBar.Append(self.createMenu(menuItems), menuLabel)`.
`createMenu(menuItems)` How it works?I mean the object that `menu` points to has been deleted.

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no such thing as a static variable in Python, and functions don't return variables, they return values (in pretty much any language, not just Python).

Comment: `menuBar` is not static and goes away when the function goes out of scope. I'm not sure what gave you this impression.

Comment: What makes you think `menuBar` is a static variable (which Python doesn't have anyway)? It's just a variable local to the function it's in and "goes away" when the function returns. `SetMenuBar()` may make a copy of its current value before _it_ returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding your question. But you could try the following:

```
menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
print menuBar.__class__
```